# Open a URL at a specific time with a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scheduled-tasks

I have a Chrome extension that I am using to run some batch jobs on a site in the early hours of the morning. I already have a content script in place to run when this URL is called in Chrome and complete all the necessary jobs. I'm having a problem now figuring out the best way to string this to a scheduler so this URL gets opened automatically in a Chrome tab at 3:00 am. I am running all this code in a dedicated Azure Virtual Machine so there won't be any user logged in when the script is set to run. When the new tab has finished it's work it will close automatically, this I have already handled.

So far I have experimented with using the Windows Task Scheduler to open Chrome with the URL passed in as an argument. This method however is proving to be somewhat unreliable!

If I leave Chrome open on the Virtual Machine, is there any native Chrome API I can use to open a tab at a specific time with a URL? I've also used the following javascript function in a separate page to trigger the URL to open, however I have no mechanism to test if it's already running in another tab so this code would result in endless new tabs being opened, unless it could be adapted to check if the URL is already open, and I think this will be outside the scope of Javascript on it's own.

```
var myUrlToCall = "http://www.myspecialurl.com/runme.html";

//IS 3 AM YET?
function runTimer() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var dtNow = new Date();
        var hoursNow = dtNow.getHours() * 1;
        if (hoursNow >= 3) {
            //Open new window here (but how can I know if it's already open?)
            window.open(myUrlToCall);
        } else {
            runTimer();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` here, it's much simplier. It wouldn't solve your problem, though.

Comment: Thanks @Riateche, I think it should make the code cleaner though. I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Why are you using chrome instead of wget or curl for this?

Comment: Because the Chrome Extension needs to interact with a specific 3rd party website and the initial call triggers a cascade of events where the extension steps through the site and runs various checks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/) API is a perfect fit for your use case, to be used at an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/event_pages/).

```
function createAlarm() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    if (now.getHours() >= 3) {
        // 3 AM already passed
        day += 1;
    }
    // '+' casts the date to a number, like [object Date].getTime();
    var timestamp = +new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 3, 0, 0, 0);
    //                        YYYY               MM              DD  HH MM SS MS
    
    // Create
    chrome.alarms.create('3AMyet', {
        when: timestamp
    });
}

// Listen
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name === '3AMyet') {
        // Whatever you want
    }
});
createAlarm();
```

About creating the tab: The [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) method can be used to check for the existence of a tab, and open a new one if necessary. I assume that you want to focus an existing tab if needed:

```
var url = '...';
chrome.tabs.query({
    url: url
}, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length === 0) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url:url, active: true });
    } else {
        // Focus first match
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { active: true });
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks! The chrome.alarms method looks promising. I'm currently working through the chrome.tabs.query method to iterate the tabs (in a background.js) and send a response to the content-script. I'm thinking however chrome.tabs.query cannot send a response? That said, the method of creating or updating that you mention may be even better! This has completed a large part of the puzzle for me, thanks again!

Comment: A slight modification needed here now.getYear() yields 113 and should be now.getFullYear(). This was causing the alarm to fire onload as the epoch time was coming back as a huge minus number.

Comment: Awesome solution. But are there any updates after 6 years? Or it is still the best option