# How to make a chrome extension that automatically run at specific time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want make a chrome extesnion that will automatic run at midnight, and open a perticular url?

```
{
    "manifest_version":3,

    "name": "Bot",
    "version": "0",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "alarms",
        "storage"
    ],

    "background": {
         "service_worker": "background.js"
    },



    "content_scripts": [{

            "matches": ["my url"]
            "js": ["content.js"]
        
    }]

}
```

I want that my chrome extension automatically run at specific time every day.

Comment: Use chrome.alarms. [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/)

Answer (score 1):

The `chrome.alarms` API is a perfect fit for your use case, to be used at an event page.

```
function createAlarm() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    if (now.getHours() >= 3) {
        // 3 AM already passed
        day += 1;
    }
    // '+' casts the date to a number, like [object Date].getTime();
    var timestamp = +new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 3, 0, 0, 0);
    //                        YYYY               MM              DD  HH MM SS MS
    
    // Create
    chrome.alarms.create('3AMyet', {
        when: timestamp
    });
}

// Listen
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name === '3AMyet') {
        // Whatever you want
    }
});
createAlarm();
```

About creating the tab: The `chrome.tabs.query` method can be used to check for the existence of a tab, and open a new one if necessary. I assume that you want to focus on an existing tab if needed:

```
var url = '...';
chrome.tabs.query({
    url: url
}, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length === 0) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url:url, active: true });
    } else {
        // Focus first match
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { active: true });
    }
});
```

You can read more about it on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583574/open-a-url-at-a-specific-time-with-a-chrome-extension)